# Question moved to Meta doesn't trigger moderator's notification

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, notifications, migration, per-site-meta

Just moved [a question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/489516/181472) from Ru.SO to Meta Ru.SO. This action didn't trigger a moderator's notification (when black diamond becomes blue and the question appears in the feed).

First line in the feed says "mod's message... 1 hour ago":

> [image: don't worry, this doesn't reveal any user's identity]

I think it should behave just as with any other question asked directly on Meta (which always trigger notifications). Other mods do not know about the question, so they still need the notification.

Comment: Do you normally get notification of new meta questions?

Comment: I do remember getting notifications for questions migrated to Meta, so this did work at some point.

Comment: @ChrisF: sure, I get notified about each question on my Meta.

Comment: @NickVolynkin - on SO we don't but on other sites we do, so I was just checking to see which model you followed - SO or everyone else.

Comment: @ChrisF: that's quite reasonable, considering the daily amount of questions on Meta SO.